# Is there a way to change to a ip addess in URL using yq command

Tags: yaml, yq

I am looking how can i change from **localhost to ip address** using yq command. Below is the example

from :

```
  api:
    in: http://localhost:1141/test-new-api/rest/apiIntegration
    out: http://localhost:1141/test-new-api/rest/outputIntegration
```

TO:

```
  api:
    in: http://192.168.0.1:1141/test-new-api/rest/apiIntegration
    out: http://192.168.0.1:1141/test-new-api/rest/outputIntegration
```

Correct format

```
url:
  api:
    in: http://localhost:1141/test-new-api/rest/apiIntegration
    out: http://localhost:1141/test-new-api/rest/outputIntegration
  db:
    in: http://localhost:1121/test-new-api/rest/aggregateTaskQuery
    out: http://localhost:1121/test-new-api/rest/insertQuery
  rule: http://localhost:1131/test-new-api/rest/executeRule
  metrics: http://localhost:1191/test-new-api/rest/addTaskMetrics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Substitute / Replace string](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#substitute-replace-string) functionality of [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)

```sh
yq e '.api[] |= sub("localhost:", "192.168.0.1:")'
```

For the updated question to replace on multiple nodes, do

```sh
yq e '.url |= (.api[],.db[],.rule,.metrics) |= sub("localhost:", "192.168.0.1:")'
```